# Run as administrator from command line on Windows 8

Tags: command-line, administrator, hosts-file, runas

I am trying to run Notepad as admin so I can edit my hosts file from the command line.

I have tried `runas /user:(myusername)\administrator "notepad c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"` I then input my password and I get

> RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - notepad
>   c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts 1327: Account restrictions are
>   preventing this user from signing in. For example: blank pa sswords
>   aren't allowed, sign-in times are limited, or a policy restriction has
>   been enforc ed.

PS: I know if I give permission to my user account I can edit it without running as admin. But I'd like to know how to do this without having to change permissions on the hosts file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, the *reason* this doesn't work is the security model in Windows Vista and newer.
 An account in the administrators group still runs everything not explicitly elevated as a limited user. The exception is the `Administrator` account, which runs *everything* elevated. For this reason, it is considered generally bad to use as your login account, and is normally disabled.

You could enable it and then `runas` to invoke as that account. That introduces a few problems - now you're running with the environment of a different user, which could have different environment variables set.<sup>1</sup>

The better way to do this would be actually elevate as your current user via UAC. Unfortunately, the standard command prompt doesn't include that capability - but both third party programs and the built-in PowerShell and WSHell (VBScript) can do so.

---

Borrowing [from my other answer](https://superuser.com/a/656876/117590), you can invoke the PowerShell command directly with `powershell -c`:

```
powershell -c start -verb runas notepad C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

which basically tells PowerShell to run the following (`start` is aliased to `Start-Process`):

```
Start-Process -Verb "runas" notepad C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

The trick here is passing the verb `runas`, triggering UAC.

[Neither `Start-Process -Verb runas` nor the standard cmd `runas` will pass the current working directory](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/12/11/6648397.aspx), so **always use the full path** in any commands you elevate in this fashion.

Also note that some arguments like `-c` may clash with `Start-Process` arguments, so the safest way is:

```
powershell "-c start -verb runas commandname -argumentlist 'arg1 arg2'"
```

---

<sup>1 Note: this only applies to the *user*'s environment variables. Environment variables you set in a parent process [are not passed on by UAC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2008/10/29/why-don-t-elevated-applications-receive-environment-variables-set-by-non-elevated-calling-process.aspx)! This also applies to `runas`, and it's even worse there because you won't even get the correct user's vars.</sup>

Comment: It didn't work for me with the double-quotes.

Comment: @Ghodmode Could you give an example of the line you tried to run? If you're referring to the last example, try moving the first quote to after the `-c`. (so `-c "start` instead of `"-c start`)

Comment: Note that the powershell process does *not* have to be run elevated in order to run a program as administrator.

Comment: Strange that it was working before a Windows 10 2019-03 update.

Answer (score 13):

Most likely, you haven't yet enabled the administrator account.

Here are [instructions for enabling the administrator account](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9650-built-administrator-account-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html).

You'll also find [more info on runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525(v=ws.10).aspx) on the Microsoft site.

Comment: My administrator user stopped working after Windows 10 2019-03 update, this command fixed it `net user administrator /active:yes`

Answer (score -1):

One thing that you could try is opening command prompt as admin and running notepad through there. Just type `Notepad`. After you do that from there you can click file then open and navigate to the hosts file and open it. Finally, you can just save like normal.